# How to properly query from multiple side of the relation in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a book entity that has multiple authors. I want to query all books written by particular author but query result should also return all the author for those books.

```java
class Book {
  String title;
  List<Author> authors;
}
```

I am either able to get all the book written by particular author and not get other authors of the book with following query

```sql
SELECT b.*, a.*
FROM book AS b
INNER JOIN book_author AS ba ON ba.book_id = b.book_id
INNER JOIN author AS a ON a.author_id = ba.author_id
WHERE a.author_id = 1;
```

Or get all the books and filter books written by that particular author in the backend.

What is the best way to get the desired row set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try tweaking your WHERE condition.

Your currently using a single author to filter results. What you really want is to filter by all books that have that author, something like this;

```
SELECT b.*, a.*
FROM book AS b
INNER JOIN book_author AS ba ON ba.book_id = b.book_id
INNER JOIN author AS a ON a.author_id = ba.author_id
WHERE ba.book_id IN (SELECT bai.book_id FROM book_author bai WHERE bai.author_id = 1);
```